# Does reparametrization preserve critical points?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Consider the convex optimization problem
$$
\min_{x \in R^n} ~f(x),
$$
for a convex function $f : R^n \to R$.

Now let $g : R^n \to R^n$ be a smooth, bijective map with smooth inverse $g^{-1}$. Then we can optimize the problem
$$
\min_{y \in R^n} ~f(g^{-1}(y)).
$$
This problem is not always convex in y. However, I suspect that every critical point of $\min_y h(y)$ with $h = f \circ g^{-1}$ corresponds actually to a global minimum of the convex problem. It appears simple, but I have trouble showing this. Any help is appreciated.

I would also be interested in the constrained case, i.e., $x \in C$ for some convex set $C$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I assumed smoothness of $f$ and tried to write down the optimality condition for the second problem. Then, I attempted to prove that it implies the optimality conditions of the first problem.  In the condition, the Jacobian of g appears for which I don't know whether it is full-rank. 

The setting for non smooth f seems much more challenging, since it seems difficult to use the chain-rule.